# How to iterate over a list in a condition

Tags: ansible

I have two hosts: One in production, another one in test.
`test` and `prod` are defined in a fact file available on target hosts (nodes).

```ini
[node]
type= prod
```

or

```ini
[node]
type= test
```

I have the following variables defined:

```yaml
users:
  - username: A
    password: password_A
    update_password: always
    home: /home/A
    state: present
    nodes: ['test', 'prod']


  - username: B 
    password: passwd_B
    update_password: always
    home: /home/B
    state: present
    nodes: ['test']
```

My `A` user shall be installed on production and test hosts.
`B` user  only on test host.

Hereafter a role that works fine if i use a single value for nodes definition.

```yaml
- name: create users
  ansible.builtin.user:
    name: "{{ item.username }}"
    password: "{{ item.password }}"
    uid: "{{ item.uid }}"
    home: "{{ item.home }}"
    create_home: yes
    group : "{{ item.group }}"
    shell: /bin/bash
    state: present
    expires: -1
  with_items:
      - "{{ users }}"
  when:  item.nodes  ==  ansible_local['myfact']['node"']['type']
```

I don't know how to loop on each value of the `item.nodes` list and compare them with the local fact value. `item.nodes[0]`, `item.nodes[1]`, ...  I might have other type of host, not only `prod` and `test`.
I tried `subelements` without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to iterate anything in your condition, you can assert that an element is in a list with the [`in` test](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-tests.in).

So your condition needs to be

```yaml
when: ansible_local.myfact.node.type in item.nodes
```

Answer (score 0):

Q: ***"A user shall be installed on production and test hosts.
B user only on test host."***

A: Condition is not needed. Use filter *selectattr* and [test if a list contains a value](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-if-a-list-contains-a-value). For example, given the inventory for testing

```
shell> cat hosts
prod type=prod
test type=test
```

The task

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "Create user {{ item.username }}"
      loop: "{{ users|selectattr('nodes', 'contains', type) }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.username }}"
```

iterates selected users only

```yaml
TASK [debug] ******************************************************
ok: [prod] => (item=A) => 
  msg: Create user A
ok: [test] => (item=A) => 
  msg: Create user A
ok: [test] => (item=B) => 
  msg: Create user B
```